# WiX e .msp identify if it requires update by (fileexists)

Tags: wix, windows-installer, msi-patch

I'm still new to the WiX world, this week I discovered the .msp extension used for updating.

I would like to know if I can identify a possible update through (fileexists)

Why that? So I wouldn't have to run the MSI on past machines, only to be able to run the MSP later.

Or if there is any way to start the .msp without having run the .msi before.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Patches don't work that way. To get what you want, use major upgrades -- they work for initial install and later updates. As I said at https://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/12/29/neither-more-nor-less/:

> Major upgrades aren’t so limited: They can change anything in a product, but also support as few changes as a small update. So even if you’re changing only a few files, you can still use major upgrades. Think of major as an upper limit on the set of changes, not the lower limit on the type of upgrade you need.

Comment: Thanks! @bob arnson is there a possibility that an .msp file could run on a computer that did not run the .msi?

Comment: No, patches can only be installed "on top of" an .msi.

Comment: I understand Bob thanks friend!

I have 18 pc's and 3 of them were formatted and don't have the installer.msi installation, would there be any solution for me to run the patch on 18 and solve the problem?

Comment: You can't install a patch without a matching .msi.

Comment: Yes Bob, I have an .msi, but can I run an .msp with an updated .msi? on a pc where the .msi has never been run?

Sorry if I'm asking silly questions.

Comment: An .msp can target different .msis so the answer is "maybe." It depends on the .msp.

Comment: Bob, can you help me? I want to create a .msp that runs on a few pc's that have never been run .msi

Thank you very much, you are being very considerate.

Comment: That's not possible. MSPs only install with matching MSIs. If you control the MSI, make it a major upgrade and you can use it on all machines.